# BizTalk 2009 WSE 2.0 Adapters Availability

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

Will the WSE 2.0 adapters plus SP1 work with BizTalk 2009?

I need to call an .asmx webservice and pass a WSE user/pass.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. WSE 2.0 is dead. WSE3.0 is dying too. Microsoft is encouraging everyone to upgrade to WCF. You can write a WCF service that calls your WSE 2.0 service though.

I would suggest you extract your business logic out of your service to make the transition to WCF just for the performance improvement.

Comment: If a vendor supplies us .asmx web service that reuires the ws-security login, and we need to communicate with them, then we have no choice.

Comment: So the asmx can only be called from a BizTalk adapter, not from a web service or a windows form app that hosts a WCF service? I don't know WSE has such restriction.

Comment: Other questions I've asked have shown that WCF can call .asmx with WS-Security.  I was not aware that it could when I asked this question originally.